# Service stack: Difference between GetSession and SessionAs<t>

Tags: c#, servicestack

Are there any significant differences between `Service.GetSession()` and `Service.SessionAs<T>()` and how they resolve the sessions?

I'm maintaining this code that makes use of one in some requests and uses the later in others. Are there interchangeable or are their some other considerations?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly this difference

```
public virtual IAuthSession GetSession(bool reload = false)
{
    var req = this.Request;
    if (req.GetSessionId() == null)
        req.Response.CreateSessionIds(req);
    return req.GetSession(reload);
}

protected virtual TUserSession SessionAs<TUserSession>()
{
    var ret = TryResolve<TUserSession>();
    return !Equals(ret, default(TUserSession))
        ? ret 
        : Cache.SessionAs<TUserSession>(Request, Response);
}
```

I have never used any of them, but it seems that they should not be randomly interchanged. You can browse this source code [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs) and figure out how significantly different they are. It's hard to tell at the first glance due to the lack of documentation

Comment: I went that far. and I also tried something like this
   `var s2ession = (RHServerAuthSession) this.GetSession();`
   `var session = this.SessionAs<RHServerAuthSession>();`

   `var s3ession = (RHServerAuthSession)this.GetSession();`
   `var se4ssion = this.SessionAs<RHServerAuthSession>();`

and it is returning the same session with the same id every time. Hence the question :)

Comment: Since I have never used them, I can't be of more service to you. I just tried to look at the problem from the source code point of view which is surprisingly quite often the right one. I would recommend asking this question on their github.