# ServiceStack Razor not rendering pages correctly after upgrade to 4.x

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

After upgrading the ServiceStack libraries on my website from 3.9.71 to 4.0.33, I noticed that ServiceStack.Razor is no longer rendering pages correctly. It appears to not be reading the layout.cshtml file. The pages load without the layout and without an error or warning. I've tried putting the layout.cshtml file in /Views/_layout.cshtml and /Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml.

In addition to replacing the packages during the upgrade, I also made the necessary changes to the Web.config file. Here is a snippet from my Web.config file. Please let me know if this is helpful or if I need to provide other information. Any help would be appreciated.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="servicestack:license" value="{LICENSE_KEY_HERE}" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </handlers>
        <modules>
            <add name="RightsModule" type="UI.security.RightsHttpModule" />
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.google.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://google.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <!-- Required for MONO -->
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RightsModule" type="UI.security.RightsHttpModule" />
            <add name="Airbrake" type="SharpBrake.NotifierHttpModule, SharpBrake" />
        </httpModules>
        <httpHandlers>
            <!-- razor -->
            <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
            <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
            <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <!-- add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/ -->
            </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="/optimize/login.cshtml" protection="All" timeout="1440" name="AudiencePoint" path="/app" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="/optimize" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc" />
        <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
                <add namespace="UI" />
                <add namespace="System" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <location path="optimize">
        <system.web>
            <httpHandlers>
                <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
            </httpHandlers>
        </system.web>
        <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <handlers>
                <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    </configuration>`

Comment: Try putting the layout in `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: Yes, I tried putting the layout in /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml. That's what I meant to say earlier at the end of the first sentence. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: We'll need more info about the error to be able to repro. One way to localize the problem is to start from an empty ServiceStack Razor solution then slowly copy over the Razor Views into the new project, ensuring that it still works as your copying over the assets. Then use that to compare what's different in the old project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started with a new project and followed the steps on this website [http://mediocresoft.com/things/servicestack-quick-start](http://mediocresoft.com/things/servicestack-quick-start) to create a very simple example and the Razor views still did not render. Only the ServiceStack generated snapshot renders. My environment is VS 2013, IIS 8.0 Express, .Net framework 4.5 and the ServiceStack 4.0.33 packages from NuGet. Would you be able to replicate this small example?

Comment: That looks like a tutorial for `v3`, can you try creating a new project from the [ServiceStackVS VS.NET Template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Creating-your-first-project) and select **ServiceStack ASP.NET with Razor**. If you're still having issues upload a small project into a GitHub repo and I'll let you know what's wrong with it.

Comment: I've uploaded a small project to [GitHub](https://github.com/tim-ojo/SampleSSRazorWebApp). Please take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that you're using lowercase `_layout` whilst it should be `_Layout`, but this is the default so it's not even required. I've also refactored your use of typed sessions and mocked your APSession class since it wasn't included, checkout [this commit for the fixes](https://github.com/mythz/SampleSSRazorWebApp/commit/1521caa236fd8435ea8779c2322d568c64398cca)

Comment: Thanks a lot @mythz. The sample project is rendering the Layout now. I applied the changes to the main project but I'm still not getting the html to render correctly so my plan is to start a new project and pull in the pages and code from the old project like you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that my code used the ServiceStack.Service.GetSession() method instead of the ServiceStack.Service.SessionAs() method to retrieve the UserSession. Not sure why this worked in 3.9.x but after I changed it, it started rendering in 4.0.x.

For the difference between the two methods checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633428/service-stack-difference-between-getsession-and-sessionast) stackoverflow question. They can't be used interchangeably.